# event method's not called

Tags: methods, c++-cli, custom-events

I'm working on a C++/CLI project and I'm new in it.In my project I have 2 forms, one is mainpage and the other one is Loginpage.

I want to have an event that when it logins successfully in the Loginpage, starts to get some jpeg pictures from the server.

I have defined the delegate, event and the method for it as below. It compiles completely and runs, but when the event is fired, it doesn't run the method.

I don't find an answer for it. I was wondering if you could help me?

MainPage.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "IPPort.h"
#include "Login.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Utils.h"


namespace UIv10 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

public ref class MainPage : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MainPage(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Login ^ loginpage = gcnew Login();
        loginpage->JPEGgenerate += gcnew UIv10::Login::JPEGgeneratorEventHandler(this, &MainPage::OnJPEGgenerate);
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~MainPage()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip^  menuStrip1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  fileToolStripMenuItem;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  connectToolStripMenuItem;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStrip^  toolStrip1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripButton^  toolStripButton1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(MainPage::typeid));
        this->menuStrip1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip());
        this->fileToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
        this->connectToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
        this->toolStrip1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStrip());
        this->toolStripButton1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripButton());
        this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->menuStrip1->SuspendLayout();
        this->toolStrip1->SuspendLayout();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
        this->SuspendLayout();

        // 
        // menuStrip1
        // 
        this->menuStrip1->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(1) { this->fileToolStripMenuItem });
        resources->ApplyResources(this->menuStrip1, L"menuStrip1");
        this->menuStrip1->Name = L"menuStrip1";
        // 
        // fileToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this->fileToolStripMenuItem->DropDownItems->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(1) { this->connectToolStripMenuItem });
        this->fileToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"fileToolStripMenuItem";
        resources->ApplyResources(this->fileToolStripMenuItem, L"fileToolStripMenuItem");
        // 
        // connectToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this->connectToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"connectToolStripMenuItem";
        resources->ApplyResources(this->connectToolStripMenuItem, L"connectToolStripMenuItem");
        this->connectToolStripMenuItem->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MainPage::connectToolStripMenuItem_Click);
        // 
        // toolStrip1
        // 
        this->toolStrip1->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(1) { this->toolStripButton1 });
        resources->ApplyResources(this->toolStrip1, L"toolStrip1");
        this->toolStrip1->Name = L"toolStrip1";
        // 
        // toolStripButton1
        // 
        resources->ApplyResources(this->toolStripButton1, L"toolStripButton1");
        this->toolStripButton1->Name = L"toolStripButton1";
        this->toolStripButton1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MainPage::toolStripButton1_Click);
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        resources->ApplyResources(this->pictureBox1, L"pictureBox1");
        this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
        this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // MainPage
        // 
        resources->ApplyResources(this, L"$this");
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->toolStrip1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->menuStrip1);
        this->MainMenuStrip = this->menuStrip1;
        this->Name = L"MainPage";
        this->WindowState = System::Windows::Forms::FormWindowState::Maximized;
        this->menuStrip1->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->menuStrip1->PerformLayout();
        this->toolStrip1->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->toolStrip1->PerformLayout();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
#pragma endregion

private: System::Void toolStripButton1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             IPPort ^ ipportpage = gcnew IPPort();
             ipportpage->Show();
}
private: System::Void connectToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         /*IPPort ^ ipportpage = gcnew IPPort();
         ipportpage->Show();*/
         Login^ L = gcnew Login();
         L->Show();
}

     void OnJPEGgenerate(System::Object^ sender,System::EventArgs^ e);
};
}


void UIv10::MainPage::OnJPEGgenerate(System::Object^ sender,System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to Login", "Attention", MB_OK);
    throw gcnew System::NotImplementedException();
}
```

Login.h:

```
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#ifndef Login_h
#define Login_h

bool FLogin(char use[128], char pass[64]);

#pragma once

namespace UIv10 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;



    public ref class Login : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {

    public: delegate void JPEGgeneratorEventHandler(System::Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e);
    public: event JPEGgeneratorEventHandler^ JPEGgenerate; 
    public:
        Login(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Login()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnCancel2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnLogin;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtbPassword;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  txtbUserName;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  lblPassword;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  lblUserName;


    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->btnCancel2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->btnLogin = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->txtbPassword = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->txtbUserName = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->lblPassword = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->lblUserName = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnCancel2
            // 
            this->btnCancel2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 174);
            this->btnCancel2->Name = L"btnCancel2";
            this->btnCancel2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(71, 23);
            this->btnCancel2->TabIndex = 11;
            this->btnCancel2->Text = L"Cancel";
            this->btnCancel2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // btnLogin
            // 
            this->btnLogin->Location = System::Drawing::Point(61, 174);
            this->btnLogin->Name = L"btnLogin";
            this->btnLogin->Size = System::Drawing::Size(71, 23);
            this->btnLogin->TabIndex = 10;
            this->btnLogin->Text = L"Login";
            this->btnLogin->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->btnLogin->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Login::btnLogin_Click);
            // 
            // txtbPassword
            // 
            this->txtbPassword->Location = System::Drawing::Point(112, 109);
            this->txtbPassword->Name = L"txtbPassword";
            this->txtbPassword->PasswordChar = '*';
            this->txtbPassword->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 20);
            this->txtbPassword->TabIndex = 9;
            this->txtbPassword->Text = L"roseek";
            // 
            // txtbUserName
            // 
            this->txtbUserName->Location = System::Drawing::Point(112, 65);
            this->txtbUserName->Name = L"txtbUserName";
            this->txtbUserName->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 20);
            this->txtbUserName->TabIndex = 8;
            this->txtbUserName->Text = L"roseek";
            // 
            // lblPassword
            // 
            this->lblPassword->Location = System::Drawing::Point(47, 117);
            this->lblPassword->Name = L"lblPassword";
            this->lblPassword->Size = System::Drawing::Size(59, 12);
            this->lblPassword->TabIndex = 7;
            this->lblPassword->Text = L"Password";
            // 
            // lblUserName
            // 
            this->lblUserName->AutoSize = true;
            this->lblUserName->Location = System::Drawing::Point(47, 73);
            this->lblUserName->Name = L"lblUserName";
            this->lblUserName->Size = System::Drawing::Size(60, 13);
            this->lblUserName->TabIndex = 6;
            this->lblUserName->Text = L"User Name";
            // 
            // Login
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnCancel2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->btnLogin);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtbPassword);
            this->Controls->Add(this->txtbUserName);
            this->Controls->Add(this->lblPassword);
            this->Controls->Add(this->lblUserName);
            this->Name = L"Login";
            this->Text = L"Login";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion

    private: System::Void btnLogin_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 String ^ username;
                 String ^ password;

                 username = this->txtbUserName->Text;
                 password = this->txtbPassword->Text;

                 using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
                 IntPtr Cusername = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(username);
                 char* UserName = static_cast<char*>(Cusername.ToPointer());
                 IntPtr Cpassword = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(password);
                 char* Password = static_cast<char*>(Cpassword.ToPointer());

                 bool Lret = FLogin(UserName, Password);
                 if (Lret == TRUE)
                 {
                     JPEGgenerate(this,e);
                     this->Close();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     JPEGgenerate(this, e);
                     MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to Login", "Attention", MB_OK);
                     this->Close();
                 }
    }
};
}
#endif
```

Sorry for the long codes, I just don't know where the problem may be.

The actuall problem is that when JPEGgenerate(this,e); runs it should run OnJPEGgenerate. But it doesn't.

Comment: You wrote code that compiles, it however doesn't exactly look logically correct.  You create *two* instances of the Login class, once in the MainPage constructor, again in the connectToolStripMenuItem_Click() function.  Which is the real one?  You only show the latter one.  So that's the one whose event you need to subscribe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems wrong for me:

```
MainPage(void)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Login ^ loginpage = gcnew Login();
    loginpage->JPEGgenerate += gcnew UIv10::Login::JPEGgeneratorEventHandler(this, &MainPage::OnJPEGgenerate);
}
```

As I understood you should keep reference to such object, otherwise, it will be deleted (and appropriated handler will not be invoked)

Other piece of code (it will not contain registration of event's handler)

```
 Login^ L = gcnew Login();
 L->Show();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. So you say the handler doesn't invoke because it's already deleted? How can I fix It?

Comment: That `loginpage` instance in the `MainPage` constructor is *not* used, you can safely remove it. Add your event handler to the `L` instance in `connectToolStripMenuItem_Click`

Comment: @Eoaneh, you should try fix code following  Lucas Trzesniewski's hint